# difference between denial and refusal

Tags: vocabulary

https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1837_aae/page19.shtml

This page says:

The opposite of 'deny' would be 'admit'.

'Accept' could be the opposite of 'refuse', 'reject' and 'decline'.

Do we '**admit**' resurrection or do we '**accept**' resurrection? I think we '**believe in**' resurrections. So what should be the opposite?

*Note: A question to only those believing in the Book. 'Others' don't bother themselves here.*

Comment: Disbelieve, or doubt.

Comment: _Admit_ is the opposite of _deny_ only in the sense of admitting to something _you_ have done; we don't admit a belief.